# Adding comments in meteor. Error : 'insert failed'

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, simple-schema

I've been hammering my head for the last couple of hours. I know I'm making a stupid mistake, but I cannot seem to get the code to work. I keep getting `insert failed: Error: fritkotId is required` error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to add comment functionality into one of my objects. This is what I have now...

```
# collections/comments.js

// Schema Definitions
CommentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    body: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Body'
    },
    fritkot: {
        type: String,
        label: 'fritkotId',
        autoValue: function() {
            return Session.get('fritkotId', this._id)
        },
            autoform: {
                type: 'hidden'
            }
        },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: 'User',
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Created At',
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    }
});


# collections/fritkots.js

import './comments.js

// Schema Definitions
FritkotSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    comments: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    'comments.$': {
        type: Object
    },
    'comment.$.body': {
        type: String
    },
    fav: {
        type: Boolean,
        defaultValue: false,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Name'
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Address',
    },
    postCode: {
        type: String,
        label: 'PostCode'
    },
    gemeente: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Gemeente'
    },
    info: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Description'
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: 'User',
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Created At',
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type: 'hidden'
        }
    }
});
```

#### fritkotSingle.js

```
import './fritkotSingle.tpl.jade' //  Single Fritkot View Page


// On Creation
Template.fritkotSingle.onCreated(function() {
    let self = this;


    self.autorun(() => {

        let fritkotId = FlowRouter.getParam('fritkotId');
        self.subscribe('singleFritkot', fritkotId);
    })
});



// Helpers
Template.fritkotSingle.helpers({
    fritkot: () => {
        let fritkotId = FlowRouter.getParam('fritkotId');
        let fritkot = Fritkots.findOne( { _id: fritkotId } ) || {};

        return fritkot
    },
    editable: function () {
        return Session.equals('editFritkotId', true)
    },
    // comments: function() {
    //  // let fritkot =  Fritkots.findOne( { id: Session.get(this._id)} );
    //  let fritkot =  Fritkots.findOne( { _id: this._id } );
    //  return fritkot.comments
    // },
    commentsCount: function() {
        return Comments.find( { fritkotId: this._id} ).count();
        console.log(`There are ${Comments.find( { fritkotId: this._id} ).count()} comments written by this user`);
    }
        // comments: () => {
        // look up comments that have matching fritkotId
        // loop thru comments
    // }
});
```

#### fritkotSingle.tpl.jade

```
with fritkot
    if editable
        +editFritkot
    else
        .section.section--single
            article.card.card--single
                h3.card__title= name
                p.card__content{{commentsCount}} comments
                p.card__content= address
                p.card__content
                    = gemeente
                    span.card__content= postCode
                p.card__info= info
                if fav
                    button.card__btn.btn--isDenied.toggle-fav Remove from Favorites
                else
                    button.card__btn.btn--isAllow.toggle-fav Add to Favorites
                    //- button.card__btn.toggle-fav Add to Favorites
                button.card__btn.form-delete Delete
                //- button.card__btn.btn--isEdit.form-edit Edit
                button.card__btn.form-edit Edit
.section.section--comments
    +comments
```

#### newComment.js

```
import './newComment.tpl.jade'

Template.newComment.events({
    'click .form-save': (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let body = $('.new-comment').val();


        Comments.insert({
            // check(id, String);
            body: body,
            createdAt: new Date()
        });

        console.log('A comment was inserted with this text: ' + body);
        Session.set('newComment', false);

        // FlowRouter.go('fritkotSingle');
        // console.log('redirecting');
    },
    'click .form-close': (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        Session.set('newComment', false);
    }
})
```

I'm thinking my problem is either on my Schema definitions or the way I'm calling insert on the `newComment` form. Somehow I need to pass the `fritkotId` to my a comment and insert it when I save, but I'm having problems on where to define it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**: So the problem was with my `collection/comments.js`. Apparently  declaring different  fields both in a `SimpleSchema` and when calling `Comments.insert` was not letting me add a Comment with the `fritkotId`.

I ended up commenting out the `SimpleSchema` definition for the time being.

Here is the code that actually works.

```
Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments')


// Permissions
Comments.allow({
    insert: (userId, doc) => {
        // return !! userId;
        return true
    },
    update: (userId, doc) => {
        return !! userId;
    },
    remove: (userId, doc) => {
        return !! userId;
    }
});


// Schema Definitions
// CommentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
//  body: {
//      type: String,
//      label: 'Body',
//      min: 1,
//      max: 140
//  },
//  author: {
//      type: String,
//      label: 'User',
//      autoValue: function() {
//          return this.userId
//      },
//      autoform: {
//          type: 'hidden'
//      }
//  },
//  createdAt: {
//      type: Date,
//      label: 'Created At',
//      autoValue: function() {
//          if (this.isInsert) {
//              return new Date()
//          } else if (this.isUpsert) {
//              return { $setOnInsert: new Date }
//          } else {
//              this.unset()
//          }
//      },
//      autoform: {
//          type: 'hidden'
//      }
//  },
//  lastUpdatedAt: {
//      type: Date,
//      autoValue: function() {
//          if (this.isUpdate) {
//              return new Date ()
//          }
//      },
//      denyInsert: true,
//      optional: true
//  } 
// });


// Methods
Meteor.methods({
    // updateComment: (id) => {
    //  Comments.update(id, {
    //      $set: { text:  }
    //  }),
    createComment: function (commentContent, fritkotId)  {
        check(commentContent, String);
        check(fritkotId, String);

        let currentUserId = Meteor.userId();

        if(currentUserId && fritkotId) {
            Comments.insert({
                body: commentContent,
                author: currentUserId,
                fritkotId: fritkotId,
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
        } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error('you must comment on a fritkot');
        }
    },
    updateComment: (id) => {
        // Session.set('editComment', true);
    },
    deleteComment: (id) => {
        Comments.remove(id);
    }
})

// Comments.attachSchema( CommentSchema );
```

No I need to make it work with `SimpleSchema`

Answer (score 1):

Meteor's [`Session.get(key)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) method only accepts a single argument. It appears you are passing the `Session.get()` method two arguments in your schema for the `fritkot.autoValue` entry:

```
fritkot: {
  type: String,
  label: 'fritkotId',
  autoValue: function() {
    return Session.get('fritkotId', this._id)
  },
  autoform: {
    type: 'hidden'
  }
},
```

You most likely want to do:

```
fritkot: {
  type: String,
  label: 'fritkotId',
  autoValue: Session.get('fritkotId'),
  autoform: {
    type: 'hidden'
  }
},
```

Comment: thanks but still getting the same error `debug.js:41 insert failed: Error: fritkotId is required  at getErrorObject (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=96e85f01d3cf55d67e56656b9908b5aff9c54ab8:489:15)
    at doValidate (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js?hash=96e85f01d3cf55d67e56656b9908b5aff9c54ab8:471:13)
    at Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert]`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using Blaze's `{{#with}}` method instead of `{{#each}}` or `{{each .. in}}`? `{{#with}}` could be messing with your data context and the Meteor team generally advises against its use. See http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-and-With

Comment: in your ```fritkotSingle.js```  fritkotSingle helper, could you put a console log to see if it's actually returning anything? Specifically  ```fritkotSingle```
and ```fritkot```

Comment: @Andrew Hill, well was using it because on my `fritkotSingle.js`, I have a  helper that returns that single fritkot....  `fritkot: () => { let fritkotId = FlowRouter.getParam('fritkotId');
let fritkot = Fritkots.findOne( { _id: fritkotId } ) || {};
return fritkot` Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: @blueren, I get the fritkot object. The problem I think it is how I'm linking both my comments to my fritkots on the server side.

Comment: @blueren  here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/fe671d10addf6fabe20c7af7530c9ea3) with the server/publications and all pertaining files

Comment: @D_S - looking at your Gists I dont see a `fritkotId` defined anywhere in your schemas, yet collection2 is seeing it as required. What version of Meteor are you running, is it perhaps defined elsewhere? If it isn't required, try adding an entry for it and assigning it `optional: true`.

Comment: @Andrew Hill I updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/fe671d10addf6fabe20c7af7530c9ea3). Right now I'm able to add the `comments`, but I'm still unable to attach them to that specific `fritkot`. I think the problem might be with my `subscription/publish` methods?

Comment: Are you still getting the same error `insert failed: Error: fritkotId is required`?

Comment: @Andrew Hill, I managed to fix the problem. The insertion actually was happening, I just couldn't see it. It was a problem with how I was setting my db. I updated my answer. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Awesome stuff -